# Alternative to walking arrays of arrays in NUnit?

Tags: c#, linq, nunit

I'm to work as tester on an API that serves data and uses a lot of arrays, so I decided to do some practice with NUnit, LINQ and C#.

To help me 'visualize' the `actual` result of a GruopJoin, being an array with nested arrays, I'm fabricating an equivalent `expected` object, then comparing it using `Assert`s.

Ideally I'd use

```
 Assert.That( actual, Is.EqualTo( expected ) );
```

But this fails with the following message:

> NUnitExamples.TestFixture1.LinqOuterJoinMultirelation_Anon:
>    Expected and actual are both 
>    Values differ at index [0]
>    Expected: 
>    But was:

I guess this is telling me that the object references are different. What I want to know is, Are they equivalent objects i.e. property values are all equal?

Walking the array elements properties including the nested arrays and *their* properties tell me that the objects are equivalent but if very long-winded. Is there an easier way to do the same?

Here's my code (BTW any critique of my code would be welcome as I'm learning all this from new):

```
[Test]
public void LinqOuterJoinMultirelation_Anon()
{
    Course[] curriculum = 
    { 
        new Course() { CourseId = "C1", Title = "Database" },
        new Course() { CourseId = "C2", Title = "HCI" },
        new Course() { CourseId = "C3", Title = "Op Systems" },
        new Course() { CourseId = "C4", Title = "Programming" }
    };

    ExamMark[] results = 
    { 
        new ExamMark() { StudentId = "S1", CourseId = "C1", Mark = 85 },
        new ExamMark() { StudentId = "S1", CourseId = "C2", Mark = 49 },
        new ExamMark() { StudentId = "S1", CourseId = "C3", Mark = 85 },
        new ExamMark() { StudentId = "S2", CourseId = "C1", Mark = 49 },
        new ExamMark() { StudentId = "S3", CourseId = "C3", Mark = 66 },
        new ExamMark() { StudentId = "S4", CourseId = "C1", Mark = 93 }
    };

    var actual = curriculum.GroupJoin
    (
        results, 
        c => c.CourseId, 
        r => r.CourseId, 
        (c, r) => new Performance() { CourseId = c.CourseId, Results = r.ToArray<ExamMark>() }
    ).ToArray<Performance>();

    var expected = new[] 
    { 
        new Performance 
        { 
            CourseId = "C1", 
            Results = new[] 
            { 
                new ExamMark() { StudentId = "S1", CourseId = "C1", Mark = 85 }, 
                new ExamMark() { StudentId = "S2", CourseId = "C1", Mark = 49 },
                new ExamMark() { StudentId = "S4", CourseId = "C1", Mark = 93 }
            }
        },
        new Performance 
        { 
            CourseId = "C2", 
            Results = new[] 
            { 
                new ExamMark() { StudentId = "S1", CourseId = "C2", Mark = 49 }
            }
        },
        new Performance 
        { 
            CourseId = "C3", 
            Results = new[] 
            { 
                new ExamMark() { StudentId = "S1", CourseId = "C3", Mark = 85 },
                new ExamMark() { StudentId = "S3", CourseId = "C3", Mark = 66 }
            }
        },
        new Performance { CourseId = "C4" }
    };

    //Assert.That( actual, Is.EqualTo( expected ) );

    for (int i = 0; i < actual.Count(); i++)
    {
        Assert.That( actual[i].CourseId, Is.EqualTo( expected[i].CourseId ) );

        for (int j = 0; j < actual[i].Results.Count(); j++)
        {
            Assert.That( actual[i].Results[j].StudentId, Is.EqualTo( expected[i].Results[j].StudentId ) );
            Assert.That( actual[i].Results[j].CourseId, Is.EqualTo( expected[i].Results[j].CourseId ) );
            Assert.That( actual[i].Results[j].Mark, Is.EqualTo( expected[i].Results[j].Mark ) );
        }
    }


class Course
{
    public string CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

class ExamMark
{
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public string CourseId { get; set; }
    public int Mark { get; set; }
}

class Performance
{
    public string CourseId { get; set; }
    public ExamMark[] Results { get; set; }
}
```

---

RESOLVED

I changed the classes to implement `IEquatable<T>` including overrides for `Equals` and discovered that my `expected` object was not equivalent to `actual` due to an null array reference rather than a zero element array i.e. needed to change from

```
new Performance { CourseId = "C4" }
```

to

```
new Performance { CourseId = "C4" , Results = new ExamMark[0] }
```

and now `Assert.That( actual, Is.EqualTo( expected ) );` works as intended :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `ExamMark` had a suitable `Equals` override (and it looks like the sort of class that should), and your `Performance` did (and again, it looks like the sort of class where real code using it would find that useful), then you could use.

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Otherwise, you can define an `IEqualityComparer<Performance>` and use

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual, new PerformanceComparer());
```

You can also use `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` if you don't care about the collection tested being in a particular order.

Of course, the `Equals` methods will have to walk arrays themselves, but something has to anyway (of course, return false fast on different lengths).

Comment: See update to my answer to see how I followed your advice to a resolution of the issue. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to compare collections you are better off using `CollectionAssert.AreEqual(IEnumerable expected, IEnumerable actual)`.

There is an overload for this method that takes an [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx) implementation for equivalence checking of the individual items in the two collections. This would be one option, writing a class that implements `IComparer` and compares two `Performance` objects.

The other alternative would be to make all your classes implement [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx). Then you could use `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` without the `IComparer` argument.